# How to combine crossProject and dependsOn

Tags: sbt, scala.js

I have a multi-project definition something like the following:

```
lazy val commonSettings = settings(
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.2",
     ...
)

lazy val core = (project in file(".")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(...
)

lazy val web = (project in file("web")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(...
).dependsOn(core)
```

The problem is that I want to set up the web project to use the Scala JS client/server model. So I need to expand the web project to use crossProject to split into the js/jvm/shared parts. But I am not sure of the best way to achieve this. If I try to do something like:

```
lazy val web = crossProject.
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(...
).jsSettings(...
).jvmSettings(...
).dependsOn(core)
```

I get a compilation error for my build.scala:

> ... type mismatch; [error]  found   : sbt.Project [error]  required:
>   org.scalajs.sbtplugin.cross.CrossClasspathDependency [error]  lazy val
>   web =
>   crossProject.settings().jsSettings().jvmSettings().dependsOn(core)
>   [error]
>   ^

Comment: Can you share the complete error message? Why do you want to extends an existing project? Have you looked at the example [here](http://www.scala-js.org/api/sbt-scalajs/0.6.1/index.html#org.scalajs.sbtplugin.cross.CrossProject)?

Comment: On the contrary, you probably want to make your `core` a cross-project, and leave `web` a normal project with `.enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave out the dependsOn for the web project.

```
lazy val webJS = web.js.dependsOn(...)
```

It made the trick for me.